# summarise(): catching non-unique values that should be unique

Tags: r, tidyverse, summarize

Using `summarise()` and `group_by`, I want to catch non-unique values that should be unique.

Example:

```
dd <- data.frame(person=rep(1:3, each=2), 
  place=rep(c("earth", "moon"), times=3), 
  height=rep(c(60, 70, 80), each=2), 
  weight=c(10, 60, 12, 72, 15, 90))
dd

  person place height weight
1      1 earth     60     10
2      1  moon     60     60
3      2 earth     70     12
4      2  moon     70     72
5      3 earth     80     15
6      3  moon     80     90
```

This works just fine:

```
byPerson <- summarise(.data=group_by(.data=dd, person), 
  height=unique(height))
byPerson

  person height
1      1     60
2      2     70
3      3     80
```

But:

```
byPerson2 <- summarise(.data=group_by(.data=dd, person), 
  height=unique(height), weight=unique(weight))
```

Earlier versions of `dplyr` used to fail, because `weight` is not unique within `person`. The current version gives this result,

```
  person height weight
1      1     60     10
2      1     60     60
3      2     70     12
4      2     70     72
5      3     80     15
6      3     80     90
```

instead of notifying the user of the error.

Is there some way of regaining the earlier behavior? Preferably by setting a flag or something, since I could check for non-unique values in code but that's more of a pain.

Comment: It is just that `summarise` no longer limit to one row per group.  The weight unique lenght is different than height, just height is replicated.  You could wrap in a list or paste the unique values i.e. `dd %>% group_by(person) %>% summarise(across(height:weight, ~ list(unique(.x))))`

Comment: Or you create a _unique flag_, for example `weight_unique = length(unique(weight)) == 1`.